# Handwriting 行書 semi-cursive online

Tags: handwriting

Hi is there any website where we can input a chinese character and watch how it is written (the process) in 行書 semi-cursive form, and not how it is written in the normal "formal" stroke. In order to know exactly how it is handwritten in semi-cursive.

Regards,

Comment: [行书字体转换器](http://www.diyiziti.com/xingshu). Only 文征明行书字体 can show both TC and SC. Others can show SC only.

Comment: Pardon me but... TC what is it? Noobie. SC is semi cursive, I assume?

Comment: also is 文征明行书字体 something that is online? And does it shows the "movement" when making the semi-cursive character?

Comment: I just realize that in stackexchange the answer you already submitted actually can be deleted...hmm...I learned something new today...

Comment: @Tomsofty33 TC = Traditional Chinese, SC = Simplified Chinese. If you like, you could install some computer fonts in the category of 行书 [would be many variations] then type [if you know about Pinyin already] the character you want then check it. If you want to study the movement, then you probably need to study the standard font 楷书 first, then find any tutorial about 行书, which would teach you how to write them [of course I have not seen tutorials in English yet, maybe there is some. Most of them should be in Chinese].

Comment: Which 行书 variations would be the most common? which variation is the one most people follow to study the semi cursive handwriting?

Comment: @Tomsofty33, Your two questions sounds very common, but it is not, it is hard to answer, because Chinese never think about it. There is no common or uncommon for calligraphy, only good or bad, you don't need to worry that others can't recognize your writings, because if you write 行书, we just can recognize it. So Chinese never think about it. All you need to do is to pick up a 字帖 that you like, and practice it. And you don't need to worry that a form of a specified character in 行书, when you practice more and more, you can figure it out by yourself easily.

Answer (score 0):

That is called 行书字典, here is 
http://tool.wikichina.com/shufa/

书法字典 always show brush writings, but it works for pen writing too, the character forms are not change too much except the simplification.

For example, I searched 书法, this is the part of the results.

[image]

Nowadays, most people write 书 as similar to the first one(wrote by 颜真卿).

I would write like this on paper. So the dictionary works for pen writings.

[image]

Comment: I don't mean to be rude AT ALL by asking this, but just to verify and clarify things,  is that last digital handwriting of yours referring to these  characters  书法 or is it referring to another set of characters? I'm still a beginner in handwriting reading. And it's quite different in appearance at least for me for the brush and pen version. My eyes are still not accustomed to, so please excuse me.

Comment: @Tomsofty33, Sorry, my example doesn't show it well. It is not easy to find the source of every styles of characters.